# Is there an alternative to SOUNDEX or metaphone that handles names with fewer collisions?

Tags: string, algorithm, text-processing, data-processing

I'm trying to find near duplicates in a large list of names by computing the metaphone key for each string, and then, within each set of possible duplicates, use something like Levenshtein distance to get a more refined estimate of duplicate likelihood.<sup>1</sup>

However, I'm finding that metaphone is heavily determined by the first characters in the strings, and so if I feed it a long list of people's names, I get huge buckets where everyone's name is "Jennifer X" or "Richard Y", but otherwise haven't got much in common.

If I reverse the string before generating the key, the results are more sensible, in that they group by last name, but still I find that the first names aren't particularly similar.

So is there a similar algorithm that samples more of the input string to produce a sound key, perhaps by using a longer key string?

---

[1] Ideally, I'd compute the string distances directly, but if my list has 10,000 names, that would mean 100,000,000 computations, which is why I'm trying to divide and conquer by sound keying each name first and only checking for similarities within the buckets. But if there's a better way, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: which version of metaphone are you using? ideally, you should match the first names and the last names separately, but if you can't do that you should set the length of the 'metaph' (metaphone encoded key) to as long as possible, unlimited if that is possible, so that the entire name is encoded. then you should run levenshtein distance between the original search string and the original, not the encoded, names in the result set

Comment: It's metaphone2 with a length of 4. I'm not sure that increasing the length will help, because it does a good job on words, but not on names. Doing each name individually seems like a good idea, but then I'm again not sure how I would find near duplicates, because instead of each name having a single string metaphone key, each name would have 2+ keys and that set of keys isn't something you can easily group by.

Comment: a length of 4 will not encode the last name if you concatenate it on the end of the first name. in any case, making the first and last name into one string will mess up the algorithm e.g. pat heimel becomes patheimel and now what should be a separate 't' and 'h' will be coded as a 'th' sound. i suggest two passes: group by last name first, then refine this list by grouping by first name, and then do the ranking on that result. concatenating the first and last names together is just cutting corners - you have to do the work to group the first names and last names separately

Comment: This is helpful. Let me give it a go and see how well it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try eudex.

It's described as "A blazingly fast phonetic reduction/hashing algorithm."

There are many easy ways to use it, as it encodes a word into a 64-bit integer with most discriminating features towards the MSB.  The hamming difference between hashes is also useful as a difference metric between words and spellings.